Find all documents whose a field is in a range of values
I have a mongodb database whose documents have a field A that is encoded in base64. I would like to retrieve all documents for which this field is in a specific list of encoded values. Here is how I do it for one encoded value:
db.my_collection.find(
  {
    A: Binary.createFromBase64('k4FyS0OWT6ujgLUAZKnsLw==', 3) 
  }
);

How can I do the same but with a list of strings not only the one written above ?

using $in? https://mongoplayground.net/p/1rPBbCDBjjf

This question is similar to: mongodb/mongoose findMany - find all documents with IDs listed in array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
